# t4Mvc and Html.BeginForm with split controller and action name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I have the following helper used in many of my views:

```
Html.BeginForm("Save", "EmailTemplate")
```

I'd like to start using t4Mvc in my project but there doesn't seem to be a BeginForm helper with just the action url property. I could use a regular `<form>` tag and then Url.Action for the action.

Is there a way to prevent me having to use `<form>` tags in my code, but at the same time use Html.BeginForm with the t4 templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
Html.BeginForm(MVC.EmailTemplate.Save())
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I add css classes and an Id for the form?

Comment: Just use the BeginForm overload that adds formMethod and htmlAttributes to the call above. It's mostly the same as without T4MVC.